# Why is DDPG an off-policy method while policy gradient is by definition on-policy?

Tags: machine-learning

Why is DDPG an off-policy method while policy gradient is by definition on-policy?

DDPG is updated in an off-policy manner while policy gradient is on-policy. So DDPG is not a policy gradient method?

Comment: what do you mean by DDPG?

Comment: Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient